# Как найти простое число в списке?

Tags: python, простые-числа

Как можно найти простыe числa в последовательности десятичных, целых, отрицательных чисел и слов?
я попробовал решить это таким образом:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= n and n % d != 0:
        d += 2
    return d * d > n
print(isPrime(2.24))
```

и в данном примере выдает True, хотя 2.24 не простое число, то есть программа не рабочая и считает десятичные, отрицательные числа ВСЕ без исключения за простые

А также выдает ошибку, когда встречает слово типа `str()`

Comment: По определению простого числа - это __натуральное число__ больше единицы. Натуральное число, в свою очередь, это __целое число__ строго больше нуля. Поэтому ваш вопрос непонятен

Comment: @MaxU я знаю, но как исправить программу чтобы работала только для таких числ? просто она выполняет для всех числе в том числе отрицательных и десятичных

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. проверить число на соответствие типу `int`

   ```
    if isinstance(n, int) is False:
        return False
   ```
2. получить значение по модулю:

   ```
    value = abs(n)
   ```
3. искать делители от `2` до `math.sqrt(n)`
4. если не найдены - число простое

т.е. код:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if isinstance(n, int) is False:
        return False

    value = abs(n)

    if value == 1:
        return False

    for i in range(2, int(value**0.5)):
        if value % i == 0:
            return False

    return True

print(isPrime(2.24))
```

на счет отрицательных чисел - один момент
с одной стороны конечно по определению простое число - это натуральное число строго большее 1, так что по идее надо проверку такую:

```
    if value <= 1:
        return False
```

и не париться с абсолютным значением, но иногда приходилось считать и отрицательные простыми числами (при использовании основной теоремы арифметики), вернее не считать, а использовать отрицательные как простые при разложении

хотя для не целых чисел я бы все таки выбрасывал исключение - логически наверное более правильно это

**P.S.**

кстати для простого числа есть и другое определение для которого код будет вот таким коротким, без проверки на 1 и отрицательные числа:

```
return len([i for i in range(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0]) == 2
```

Comment: `int` это класс а `type` для класса всегда возвращаеть `type`

Comment: @Danis, да, точно, спасибо за замечание, исправил

Comment: @Эникейщик, дрогнул палец на =, исправил :)